# How to access docker container from mac machine using ip addr or a domain name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker desktop, I have a couple of docker containers running using docker-compose and port forwarding. I can access the containers from my mac using localhost. On the second container, I am exposing on different ports. I can see ip addresses are associated to both containers by using docker inspect, but I cannot access using the ip address.

I would like access the container from my local mac by

- dns domain
- ip address

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The IP address you are noticing is indeed associated to both containers. Those containers have IPs in the same network, but the last number is incremented. If you have exposed different ports for the container that are not used by the host machine, they can be accessed

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot directly connect to the container-private IP addresses on MacOS.](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds)  You also can't connect to them using a VM-based Docker implementation like Docker Toolbox or Kubernetes' minikube, or from a different host.  Looking up and using these IP addresses, or trying to manually set them, usually isn't a best practice.

Instead you can [use the `docker run -p` option](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) to publish a port from your container to the host.  Programs running directly on the host can access the container using `localhost` as a host name and the published port number.  This works on all platforms; on VM-based solutions use the VM's IP address instead of `localhost`; from a different host, use the Docker host's DNS name or IP address.

Comment: Thanks, I already have it working with port-forwarding and localhost. As I have 2 containers, I would like to access them by dns domain name and same port.

Comment: Try jwilder nginx proxy

Comment: The two containers are different apps.

Comment: This situation isn’t any different than running the two programs on your host not-in-Docker.  In principle you could arrange for your host to have multiple IP addresses with different DNS names and use `docker run -p 10.20.30.40:80:8888` to bind to a specific interface; but that’s a very complicated setup to just not use a port number.